# Haskell: How to use a where statement under a do block

Tags: haskell, io, where-clause

I was making a program with Haskell and it's IO, when I came across an error I don't understand. When I use a where statement after a do block it does not do the same thing as without the do block.

The program that works is:

```
import Control.Monad
prog :: IO()
prog = do m <- getLine
          n <- getLine
          p <- getLine
          replicateM_ (read m :: Int) (putStrLn n)
          replicateM_ (read m :: Int) (putStrLn p)
```

But when I replace the `read m :: Int` with a where statement like this:

```
import Control.Monad
prog1 :: IO()
prog1 = do m <- getLine
           n <- getLine
           p <- getLine
           replicateM_ (a) (putStrLn n)
           replicateM_ (a) (putStrLn p)
           where
           a = read m :: Int
```

I get the error:

```
Template.hs:23:21: error: Variable not in scope: m :: String
   |
23 |            a = read m :: Int 
   |                     ^
```

I have looked what the problem could be, and I think it has to do with the type of m, which is `IO String`. I know you have to stay in the IO type (once you are in it) to be able to work with the string. But I don't understand why the 'where' would "break out" of this IO type. To my understanding the two examples I gave are functional the same. First I thought that the error wouldn't be fixed by writing the program without the where, because the function read is from the type `read :: Read a => String -> a` and my input in the first program is also `IO String`. So why didn't my first program give me an error? Could someone explain what I understand wrong and how I can fix my program so I only have to execute `read m :: Int` once? Just some tips of how to use a where statement under a do block would also help.

*The original program I got the problem in is longer and not all relevant so I used this minimal working example to explain the essence of my question. In my original program I have multiple statements after where, so I don't want to substitute it all like I did in this example.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bindings in the `do` block are opaque to the `where` statement after it, so you can't reference anything defined in the `do` block inside the `where` statement. You don't need to either, since you can use `let` directly inside `do`:

```hs
prog1 = do m <- getLine
           n <- getLine
           p <- getLine
           -- alternatively: [m, n, p] <- replicateM 3 getLine
           -- use a let statement
           let a = read m :: Int
           replicateM_ a (putStrLn n)
           replicateM_ a (putStrLn p)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, this solved my problem! I don't understand why I didn't came across this syntax in my courses on Haskell or my search for an answer to this problem.